# Form validation not working with <select>s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript code that checks if all the fields in a form are filled, if not it pops up a bootstrap alert using jquery. This works fine with text inputs, but when checking selects, it always fires the error, even if an option is filled.

JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form[name="register"]').on("submit", function (e) {
        var username = $(this).find('input[name="username"]');
        var preferredClass = $(this).find('input[name="preferredClass"]');

        if ($.trim(username.val()) === "" || ($.trim(preferredClass.val())) === "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#formAlert").slideDown(400);
        } else {
            $("#formAlert").slideUp(400, function () {});
        }
    });

    $(".alert").find(".close").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).closest(".alert").slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

The entire code and (Kind of) working example can be found in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeQcw/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have wrong selector for your `select`

Replace this

```
var preferredClass = $(this).find('input[name="preferredClass"]');
```

With this:

```
var preferredClass = $(this).find('select[name="preferredClass"]');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/MeQcw/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your select element selector is wrong.

Try to change the selector statement:

```
$(this).find('select[name="preferredClass"]');
```

Then your validation will be ok.

Hope this is helpful for you.